# Write long instructions in IDLE

Tags: python

I am trying to type the following into the IDLE:

```
userInput = input('Enter 1 or 2: ')
if userInput == "1": print ("Hello World") print (“How
are you?”) elif userInput == "2": print ("Python
Rocks!") print (“I love Python”) else:
print ("You did not enter a valid number")
```

However, the moment after I typed the first line and pressed Enter, the program runs and asks me to Enter 1 or 2.

How can I write the full set of instructions before running?

Thanks

I've figured it out. It should be as follows:

```
userInput = input('Enter 1 or 2: ')
if userInput == "1":
    print ("Hello World")
    print ("How are you?")
elif userInput == "2":
    print ("Python Rocks!")
    print ("I love Python")
else: print ("You did not enter a valid number")
```

It seems I wrote it originally in the Shell and NOT the IDLE.

Comment: You can use `;` and write all instructions in single line

Comment: Why do you have everything smooshed together instead of writing over multiple lines? Also, are you running this in a REPL? Python doesn't just run code as it's being written unless you're writing in an interactive console. If you are, the answer then is to write in a text file and run it manually when you want it to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it functions:

```py
def actOnInput(userInput):
  if userInput == "1":
    print ("Hello World")
    print ("How are you?")
  elif userInput == "2":
    print ("Python Rocks!")
    print ("I love Python")
  else:
    print ("You did not enter a valid number")

def askForInputAndActOnIt():
  userInput = input('Enter 1 or 2: ')
  actOnInput(userInput)

askForInputAndActOnIt()
```

In a python REPL it will look something like this:

```
>>> def actOnInput(userInput):
...   if userInput == "1":
...     print ("Hello World")
...     print ("How are you?")
...   elif userInput == "2":
...     print ("Python Rocks!")
...     print ("I love Python")
...   else:
...     print ("You did not enter a valid number")
... 
>>> def askForInputAndActOnIt():
...   userInput = input('Enter 1 or 2: ')
...   actOnInput(userInput)
... 
>>> askForInputAndActOnIt()
Enter 1 or 2: 2
Python Rocks!
I love Python
>>> askForInputAndActOnIt()
Enter 1 or 2: 1
Hello World
How are you?
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open IDLE
2. Go to **Options** > **Configure IDLE** > **General**
3. Make sure you select **Open Edit Window** Radio button
4. Click Apply and OK

   Close IDLE and open it again